# JavaScript play() of audio is not working, TypeError: this.kickAudio.play is not function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> this.kickAudio.play(); is not playing  i dont know why?? Please help

> I am trying to play the audio by loop over the div but some how audio file is not playing

```
class DrumKit {
  constructor() {
    this.pads = document.querySelectorAll(".pad");
    this.playBtn = document.querySelector(".play");
    this.kickAudio = document.querySelectorAll(".kick-sound");
    this.snareAudio = document.querySelectorAll(".snare-sound");
    this.hithatAudio = document.querySelectorAll(".hithat-sound");
    this.index = 0;
    this.bpm = 150;
  }
  activePad() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  }
  repeat() {
    let step = this.index % 8;
    const activeBars = document.querySelectorAll(`.b${step}`);
    console.log(step);
    // Looping over the pads for animation
    activeBars.forEach((bar) => {
      bar.style.animation = `playTrack 0.3s alternate ease-in-out 2`;
      // Check for the active pad
      if (bar.classList.contains("active")) {
        if (bar.classList.contains("kick-pad")) {
          this.kickAudio.currentTime = 0;
          this.kickAudio.play();
        }
      }
    });
    this.index++;
  }
  start() {
    const interval = (60 / this.bpm) * 1000;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.repeat();
    }, interval);
  }
}

const drumKit = new DrumKit();

drumKit.pads.forEach((pad) => {
  pad.addEventListener("click", drumKit.activePad);
  pad.addEventListener("animationend", function () {
    // this.style.animation = '';
  });
});

drumKit.playBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  drumKit.start();
});
```

> this.kickAudio.play(); is not playing  i dont know why?? Please help

> I am trying to play the audio by loop over the div but some how audio file is not playing

Comment: What do you expect `this.kickAudio` to contain and why?

Comment: kickAudio is NodeList, not DOMElement because you use querySelectorAll

Comment: You try to use array (NodeList) of elements `.kick-sound` not one element or element inside `bar` in interetion

Comment: If every activeBars has only one element `.kick-sound` you need to change `activeBars.forEach((bar, index)=>{...})` and use `this.kickAudio[index].currentTime = 0;` But better add HTML code for your question